# Multiline Combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm trying to find an example of a multi line user editable combobox for WPF.  We've tried various things with a custom template but can't make it work.  The specific problem we're trying to solve is displaying a list of addresses in a drop down where the user can type in new ones at the same time.  Typing into a combobox is no problem.. multi line is killing us though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want show Textbox in ComboBox we can override the ItemTemplate of ComboBox. And to display multiline text we can set AcceptReturn="True" for TextBox.

```
    <ComboBox Width="250" Height="30"  >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Width="200" Height="100"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Is this what you need or am I missing something?