# WPF C# ComboBox with multiple lines and accepting returns?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Is there an easy way to do a multiline combobox in WPF C#? What do I mean by this? I mean a textbox that supports multiple lines and carriage returns; where it word wraps... It needs to have a scrollbar so that if the text in the box is taller than the height of the combobox, the user can scroll down.

In addition, because its a combobox, it needs to have a dropdown button so that the user can quickly swap between groups of text. I've tried googling for this, but I can't find anyone talking about such a combobox.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247999/2648765

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED FOR COMPLETE WORKING SOLUTION:

XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="delete.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding items}" SelectedItem="{Binding item}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="250" Height="30" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace delete
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Setup();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        ObservableCollection<Thang> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<Thang> items
        {
            get { return _items; }

            set
            {
                _items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("items");
            }
        }

        private Thang _item;
        public Thang item
        {
            get { return _item; }
            set
            {
                _item = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("item");
            }
        }

        public void Setup()
        {
            items = new ObservableCollection<Thang>();
            items.Add(new Thang("1", "One"));
            items.Add(new Thang("2", "Two"));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Thang
    {
        public Thang(string id, string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            ID = id;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not working... the textbox is not accepting carriage returns, and the text isn't wrapping once it reaches the horizontal boundary.

Comment: In addition, the dropdown menu doesn't show the items correctly.

Comment: I sure thought that would have worked.  That linked question got a check and it is the same syntax.

Comment: it does work, when you set some heights and widths, like i said.  try this:                                                               <ComboBox Height="70" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding items}" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="250" Height="30"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

Comment: @Jason Axelrod - see the answer now, its a fully working example of what you want.